# Got an Error while Installing a MongoDB on Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, mongodb

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libsnappy1v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.6 mongo-tools
  mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 153 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/92.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 187 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 181720 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_5.0.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (5.0.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (5.0.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.5.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.5.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.5.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.10_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.10_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.5.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include which version of Ubuntu you’re running? This will make it easier to offer a specific solution 

Comment: After you clean up your old mess and get your mongodb packages in order, remember to also fix `153 not upgraded`.